# How can I return a razor page from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, controller

Simply doing:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var result = new Pages.IndexModel().Page();
    result.ViewData["ID"] = id;
    return result;
}
```

Gives an error of `The context used to execute 'context' must be an instance of 'Page'. Returning a 'PageResult' from a controller is a not supported.`

I just want to pass data to a page and view it.

Comment: Do you want to show the same page using two routes? What's the point of returning a page from controller? You can redirect to the page instead of returning it.

Comment: I want to return data according the url. As in if someone goes to /thread/54 it returns a page with data from a DB using 54 for a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out without even needing a controller.

In the .cshtml add at the top `@page "{id:int?}"`

Then later down you can do

`<p>@RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()</p>`